# Как сделать так,чтобы было понятно,что Button был нажат

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.Допустим у меня есть Button.После нажатия на него,не ясно успешно ли она была нажата.Чтобы пользователю было понятно,почти во всех приложениях после нажатия на Button,её цвет немного меняется и опять становится прежним,давая знать пользователю что кнопка была успешно нажата.Вопрос в том,как сделать это? Надеюсь есть какая-то функция Button'а?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/black" /> //нажата
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> //обычно
</selector>
```

На случай, если кнопки свои картинки:

new_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

Кнопка:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/new_button" />
```

Если я правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
<item android:state_pressed="true" >//нажата
   <shape>
    ...           
   </shape>  
</item>
<item>//обычно
    <shape>
        ...
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: У меня такая ситуация что для всех Button'ов в моем приложении,я использую buttonshape.xml,где написаны формы для Button'ов. Добавил туда ваш код,но не работает.В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @andy11 обновил ответ, надеюсь поможет